# JPA ORM XML Tag

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

How to define Derived Primary key in orm.xml
example :

```
@Entity
class Entity1 {

@Id
@OneToOne
private Entity2 entity2;

....

}
```

I know to define `@Id` in ORM.xml as `<id >` tag and
`@OneToOne` in ORM.xml as `<one-to-one >` tag

but how to define combination of both ?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do what you're specifying there. You could do use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` on `Entity2` and join it that way

Comment: Use of other entities as part of an id is perfectly valid. As for the OP, what is the orm.xml that you have tried, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: @DataNucleus , In Orm.xml <attributes> tag have <id> , <basic> ,<many-to-one>, <one-to-one> etc. But how to use both combination of <id> and <one-to-one> tag in Derived Primary Key case where single attribute have both annotation `@Id` and `@OneToOne` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the docs for the JPA implementation being used are half-decent they should have examples of using the *orm.xml* (the docs for some JPA impls seem to think all you'll ever need are annotations). DataNucleus JPA has [this page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jpa/orm/compound_identity.html), which gives a simple enough example.

Comment: So the final answer is that we need to use both tag example : `<id name="user" >` and `<one-to-one name="user" >` .

Answer (score 0):

Ir your are using JPA 2, onetoone/manytoone mapping can have id="true" to specify it is part of and id.

Found here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#JPA_2.0